# app crashes when trying to use google maps on device

Tags: android, google-maps, logcat

Can anyone explain this logcat report to me, im trying to work with google maps and when i click on the maps tab on my device the app fails with the error message, 'unfortunately app has stopped working'?

```
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.softwaresearchapp/com.example.softwaresearchapp.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at com.example.softwaresearchapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:12)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     ... 18 more
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     ... 27 more
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.softwaresearchapp-1.apk
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
03-12 13:34:19.998: E/AndroidRuntime(9464):     ... 30 more
```

Comment: Show your xml file, your code and manifest file.

Comment: i think you mus have signed apk to show google maps, so if you are just trying it out on emulator or device, ti will not work, not sure if it is supposed to crash though.

Comment: If u are using Map v2, you must use MapFragment instead of MapActivity.